# Enumerate over each item of listbox to compare internal element values

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a listbox with a data template bound to a `list<class>` in the program.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="pTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ref}" Padding="5,0,0,0"/>
                <StackPanel Name="taggedA" Tag="{Binding A}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="selectedA" Text="{B}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Name="ind" Width="40" Height="40" />
            </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

On button click, I want to go over all the elments of the listbox and check if the stackPanel `taggedA`'s tag == textblock `selectedA`'s text.

This is to be done for each of the items in the list box and the data template is as above. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to compare the binding source directly:

```
ListBox l = myListBox;
for (int i = 0; i < l.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var boundObject = (MyClass)l.Items[i];
    MessageBox.Show("They are equal? " + (boundObject.A == boundObject.B));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @dbaseman. But if you are set on doing it you could do the following:

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEvent e)
{
    foreach(var item in MyListBox.Items)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        StackPanel taggedApanel = (lbi.Content as StackPanel).Children[1];
        //Do whatever you need to do here
    }
}
```